# Python how to overcome TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

My problem is that i need to have two conditions inside of an ifany() statement, the two conditions are checking if a word from a list appears in a line AND if another word from secondary list also appears in the same line. If it does then print it. I have used this if in a previous function just checking one with so i didn't need  to use And operator, I've tried reading up for alternatives but other operator's wouldn't allow me to achieve my condition.

the lword in cleanLex (cleanLex is a list created and populated inside of readfiles.py)

Here is the partial code showing function

Main.py:

```
from collections import Counter
from Categories.GainingAccess import GA
from Readfiles import *

# Speech Act Categories
CategoryGA = GA
# ----------------------

# Word hit counters
CategoryHits = []
LexiconHits = []
# ----------------------

# unsure if used at this point
cleansedLex = []
# ----------------------

# Lists to hold lines where words have been matched
matchedCatlines = []
matchedLexlines = []
TestLine = []


def languagemodel():
    for line in cleanChat.values():
        for lword in [cleanLex]:
            for cword in [CategoryGA]:
                for section in line:
                    if any(lword and cword in section for lword in
                           cleanLex and cword in CategoryGA):  # searches each section to find words matching words stored in cleanLex
                print("matched words %s and %s", "on line:    %s",
                      (lword, cword, section))


languagemodel()
```

Traceback Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Lewis Collins/Downloads/test/main.py", line 100, in <module>
    languagemodel()
  File "C:/Users/Lewis Collins/Downloads/test/main.py", line 89, in languagemodel
    cleanLex and cword in CategoryGA):  # searches each section to find words matching words stored in cleanLex
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

Any suggestions as to how to get around or fix this issue.

Comment: `cleanLex and cword in CategoryGA` is a bool.  so when you do `lword in cleanLex and cword in CategoryGA` you're trying to iterate over a bool.  what do you expect this code to do?

Comment: `if any(lword and cword in section for lword in cleanLex and cword in CategoryGA)`: what do you think this means?

Comment: What i personally thought it was going to do was when it finds lword and cword in section for the words in there list's then print, which i do apologise as i seemed to of missed my print statement off of code in that question

Comment: try `if any(lword in section and cword in section for lword in cleanLex for cword in CategoryGA)`

Comment: Maybe you meant: `if any(lword and cword in section for lword in cleanLex for cword in CategoryGA)`

Comment: @Patrick Haugh brilliant that has fixed it thanks